# Phalconphp micro mvc routing issue

Tags: phalcon

I have just started working on a simple restful service.
The folder structure I have is like so:

```
root
- /api
--/api/customers.php
```

So for example in the browser I intend to call `http://domain/api/customers/fetchall`

However, I only ever get the notFound handler called. The code in customers.php is:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault,
    Phalcon\Mvc\Micro,
    Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini;

$di = new FactoryDefault();
$di->set('config', function() {
   return new Ini("config.ini");
});

$app = new Micro($di);

/**
 * Create new customer
 */
$app->post('/create', function(){});

/**
 * Retrieve all customers
 */
$app->get('/fetchall', function() use ($app) {
    $data = array();
    $data[] = array(
        'id' => '123456',
        'name' => 'customerName',
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
});

/**
 * Find customer by name
 */
$app->get('/search/{name}', function($name){});

/**
 * Find customer by email
 */
$app->get('/search/{email}', function($email){});

/**
 * Find customer by postcode
 */
$app->get('/search/{postcode}', function($postcode){});

/**
 * Move a customer
 */
$app->put('/move/{oldpostcode}/{newpostcode}', function($oldpostcode, $newpostcode){});

/**
 * Delete customer
 */
$app->delete('/delete/{id:[0-9]+}', function($id) use ($app) {
    $response = new Phalcon\Http\Response();
    $response->setJsonContent(array('status' => 'OK'));
    return $response;
});

$app->notFound(function () use ($app) {
    $app->response->setStatusCode(404, "Not Found")->sendHeaders();
    echo 'This is crazy, but this page was not found!';
});

//echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$app->handle();
```

If i instead use **/** instead of **/fetchall** then in works but it also matches any url as well which is no good.

Appreciate the help in advance.
Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 3):

Look like a bug, but you need to specify the URL you want your application handles:

```
$app->handle(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI'));
```

Replace REQUEST_URI by what you need.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are still looking for an answer:

If you don't have .htacess please create one and add the following: as per [tutorial](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api/customers.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in your code you have to edit paths that are to be matched from say:

```
$app->get('/fetchall', function() use ($app) {
```

to:

```
$app->get('/api/customers/fetchall', function() use ($app) {
```

That's all there was to it.

Answer (score 0):

You guy may forgot to add the /api/customers prefix to your route. Try with this:

```
$app->get('/api/customers/fetchall', function() use ($app) {
$data = array();
$data[] = array(
    'id' => '123456',
    'name' => 'customerName',
);

    echo json_encode($data);
});
```